# Log4j runtime exception upon updating from 1.2.17 to 2.17.1

Tags: struct, log4j, log4j2, tomcat8, runtimeexception

I have upgrade from log4j-1.2.17 to log4j-2.17.1 with needed code changes. Code builds fine without errors. I have included proper jar files(only log4j-api-2.17.1.jar and log4j-core-2.17.1.jar) in the build path and WEB-INF path.

Upon deploying on to Tomcat 8.x version, seeing 404 error with below exception in the log file. Tried project clean, tomcat clean, rebuild etc. but no success.

Any pointers?

Thanks in advance.

```
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.61
Jan 07, 2022 4:24:29 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jan 07, 2022 4:24:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
**SEVERE: Exception starting filter [authfilter]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/log4j/Logger;**
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.populateAnnotationsCache(DefaultInstanceManager.java:403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:151)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4538)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5181)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
    ... 18 more

Jan 07, 2022 4:24:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
```

Comment: You need to use the [Log4j 1.x Bridge](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html#Log4j1.2Bridge).

Answer (score 0):

You may need his dependency sl4j to log4j adapter

```
"org.apache.logging.log4j" name="log4j-slf4j-impl" rev="2.17.0"
```